# connecting from docker container to docker host

Tags: networking, docker

I have a setup where I run all parts of my website in docker containers.  My nginx that listens on port 80 and 443 run in a container.

```
363292a98545        scivm/nginx-django-scivmcom:latest   /usr/bin/supervisord   12 days ago         Ghost               0.0.0.0:40001->22/tcp, 88.198.57.112:443->443/tcp, 88.198.57.112:80->80/tcp     lonely_feynmann
```

I want to set up a proxy to a service in another container.  This container is bound to port 3000 on the host:

```
b38c8ef72d0a        mazzolino/strider-dind:latest        wrapdocker /usr/bin/   41 minutes ago      Up 41 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 22/tcp, 27017/tcp                                       distracted_einstein
```

My iptables on the docker host look like this:

```
root@Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal /var/run # iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From within the container, I am unable to connect to port 3000 on the host machine due to the iptables configuration.

I don't want to open port 3000 to the public internet.

Is there a way to open a direct bridge between the container and the host on port 3000?

Or should I modify my iptables to accept from the docker ip range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is Docker's [link capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) [deprecated]

Just get rid of all the complicated stuff you tried to do and start using named containers and then link them to each other.

Comment: I took a look at docker link capabilities but if I understand correctly it has some issues.   1. If the child is restarted it will get a new ip address.  Then all the parents of that child would need to be restarted also to get the new environment varilabes.  2.  I have to add logic to my application to read those environment variables in order to make connections.

Comment: A restarted container (`docker restart your_container`) should keep it's IP address. Only if you run a new container based on a given image, it will get a new IP (`docker run -d image command`).

Comment: That used to be true, but at least as of docker 1.0 a "docker restart" gives the container a new ip address. Just hit this in some scripts that relied on previous behavior of the ip not changing.

Comment: While I think this is probably the right thing for the OP to do, I came here looking for an answer to the question as put.  i.e. how to link to a service on the host.

Answer (score 2):

Elias's answer is correct, but the link is long and confusing.  Here's a simple summary:

First, run the container to link to, and name it:

```
sudo docker run -d --name db training/postgres
```

Then run the other container, linking it to the first container:

```
sudo docker run -d -P --name web --link db:db training/webapp python app.py
```

The link from the first container to the second container is put into `/etc/hosts`.  So you can use it like a hostname.  For example:

```
sudo docker run --name web --link db:db training/webapp ping db
```