# Docker containers connecting to a host daemon

Tags: iptables, docker

I would like to run a daemon on the host and get the containers connect to it. I was thinking I will bind the daemon on the host to `127.0.0.1` and then have something (delegate? or is iptables enough?) forward packets from the IP of `docker0` to the daemon. So the questions are

1. How do I start something when the docker daemon starts
2. What is that something?

I am on Debian 7.

The following questions seem relevant but AFAIK aren't answers:

1. [connecting from docker container to docker host](https://serverfault.com/questions/563420/connecting-from-docker-container-to-docker-host)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413954/how-to-setup-docker-to-talk-to-non-dockerized-service-on-same-host
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: For the addressing part (127.0.0.1 will be the local IP of the container, will not connect to the host), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27564532/448734

Comment: 1. The docker daemon is started by init; you can start your process the same way. and 2. it's you that wants the daemon; you need to know what it is.  Could you try rephrasing the question?

Answer (score 1):

What I've found instead is -- most daemons are capable of using Unix sockets and you can mount that socket from the host into the container with `-v` . The ancient trick of everything is a file comes very handy. For eg `docker run -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/tmp/mysql.sock`. Inside the container you will connect to `/tmp/mysql.sock`. Also the same trick works with mounting the directory containing the socket -- this can be used to run X Windows applications within docker without SSH forward: just do `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`.